# synchronise two views with RxBinding

Tags: android, rx-java2, throttling, rx-binding

I use RxJava's throttleFirst for one second to avoid rapid button clicks, however I also want that on a button click a second button be also disabled for a second and vice versa, 
So, in short I do not allow rapid clicks on those two buttons one after another... What would you recommend? Can I achieve this using RxBinding?

```
RxView.clicks(button)
                .throttleFirst(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe {
                    doSomething()
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's one possible approach...

1. create a stream for each button
2. you'll likely need to know which button was clicked, so `map` the output of each stream to some known value that will be handled in the subscriber
3. `merge` the two streams together and `throttleFirst` that merged stream

that would all look something like this:

```
RxView.clicks(button1).map { "button1" }
        .mergeWith(RxView.clicks(button2).map { "button2" })
        .throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribeBy(
                onNext = { value ->
                    if(value == "button1") {
                        // handle button1 click
                    } else {
                        // handle button2 click
                    }
                },
                onError = {
                    ...
                }
        )
```

maybe not the most elegant, but hopefully it at least inspires some thought!